# Optimize (parallelize) execution of my "virtual machine" model

Tags: algorithm, optimization, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a simple "virtual machine" model that keeps a queue of instructions in one of the following formats:

- `unary_opcode, in_address, out_address`
- `binary_opcode, in1_address, in2_address, out_address`

where all the addresses are integers to an array of memory units.

Is there any well-known algorithm that analyzes the sequence of instructions and tries to parallelize them as much as possible without:

1. Producing a different result from sequential execution.
2. Data race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instruction A is before instruction B in the list, and ((B reads one of A's writes) OR (B and A have the same write address) OR (B writes one of A's reads)), then add a directed edge from B to A. Note this graph is a DAG, since the instructions are in a specific order.

Now calculate the "layer" of an instruction as: Instructions with no outgoing edges are layer 1. Instructions with outgoing edges only to layer N and below are layer N+1. Obviously, if an instruction has an outgoing edge to another instruction whose layer isn't known yet, don't assign it yet! There is a simple recursive routine for assigning the layers that works like DFS from each instruction.

Now an instruction with layer i can be run on cycle i (but no sooner), and this is optimal.

It is possible to do somewhat better if the parallel machine is capable of quenching writes from earlier instructions (the write-write conflict edges can be removed in that case). Precisely what I mean is, when given a batch of instructions to be executed in parallel, if some of them have the same write address, the machine deterministically writes back the result of the -last- instruction in the batch to write to that address (rather than having unspecified behavior, or nondeterministically writing back the result of -some- instruction in the batch that wrote to that address).

Comment: Thanks! Very well explained. A friend suggests "Tomasulo algorithm", which seems very involved and sophisticated. Do you think whether it's relevant or not?

Comment: It is relevant. Essentially, you can parallelize even more efficiently if you start changing the memory locations in the instructions (especially if you have unlimited spare memory locations available). I assumed your model doesn't allow this.

Comment: Suppose I do have close to unlimited spare memory, could you please give an example to illustrate what you mean by "changing the memory locations"?

Comment: Say the instruction sequence is m[x]=m[a]+m[b], m[y]=m[c]+m[d], m[v]=m[x]+m[y], m[x]=m[e]+m[f], m[y]=m[g]+m[h], m[w]=m[x]+m[y]. What it's doing is adding a+b+c+d and putting that in v and e+f+g+h and putting that in w. But because x and y are used as intermediates for both, it can't be parallelized. If you change the second x and y to different values x2 and y2, it can be parallelized better.

Comment: Wow that looks awesome. Is there a systematic way or named algorithm to change the memory locations (given that I have enough memory)?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming, that's the name for the problem. That page lists the different kinds of dependencies, and in fact I had to edit the answer as I'd missed a case. If you have unlimited memory locations, there is a simple systematic way to "rename" the memory locations: change the location of every write that is not the -first- write to a memory location to a new (unique) location. of course, the corresponding reads will need to be updated as well. the literature probably mainly deals with limited registers since that is the interesting case for hardware impl.

Comment: Marked. I think I've got enough to get started. You've been extremely helpful ;)